# .NET mailer encoding problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, unicode, encoding, smtpclient

I am using GMail (Google Apps) as an SMTP server in my website to send out emails. The mails were being sent out fine, until today, when I noticed that the encoding seemed to be wonky.

In Yahoo, the entire message is shown as Chinese characters (the mail is entirely in English).  In Hotmail, the subject of the mail was in Chinese characters.

The below is my email code:

```
Dim SMTPMail = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
SMTPMail.EnableSsl = True
SMTPMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False

Dim MailAuthentication = New NetworkCredential("mailer@website.com", "blahblah")
SMTPMail.Credentials = MailAuthentication

Dim EmailMessage As New MailMessage(New MailAddress(FromAddress), New MailAddress(ToAddress))

EmailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
EmailMessage.Subject = "Blah blah"
EmailMessage.Body = "Blah blah"
EmailMessage.Priority = Priority
EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

EmailMessage.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
SMTPMail.Send(EmailMessage)
```

The encoding in the header as shown by Yahoo are:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-16
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yet another programmer falls into the trap of plumping for what Microsoft tools misleadingly call “Unicode”. Which is actually UTF-16LE, an encoding you almost never want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire message is in English (US-ASCII), then remove this line:

```
EmailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
```

Comment: I have made this change, and this seems to have fixed the problem in Yahoo, but in Hotmail, the 'from' address is still shown in Chinese! Any idea why these email services might think the encoding is in Chinese? Edit: To clarify, just the email itself is shown in Chinese, not the "From" name.

Comment: I've modified the FromAddress into "email", "name" instead of "name <email>". This seems to have fixed the problem. Still lost as to why this is happening, though?